# Как найти где сохранены проекты в Google Console?

Tags: java, android

Я не знаю сталкивался ли кто то еще с такой проблемой как у меня, но суть такая... Хочу почистить свой аккаунт и поудалять записи о приложениях который открывал для тестов. И не могу найти где это можно сделать?

Вот скрин с проектами

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На нем указаны все проекты, как их найти? В этом меню их можно просто выбрать, а я хочу как бы уравление проектами, чтоб можно было найти кнопку Удалить.

Подскажите где это находится?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Заходите в консоль и нажимаете на кнопку бокового меню (возле надписи Google APIs):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После этого выбираете IAM и администрирование

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После чего  выбираете "Настройки" и далее у вас появляется кнопка "удалить проект"

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]